# Is there a connection between 'schmettern' and 'Schmetterling'?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Is there a connection in meaning or etymology between *schmettern* (to fling, smash, hurl, spike, blare out) and *Schmetterling* (butterfly)?

Answer (score 4):

[Duden says:](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schmetterling)

> aus dem Obersächsischen, wohl zu Schmetten; nach altem Volksglauben fliegen Hexen in Schmetterlingsgestalt umher, um Milch und Sahne zu stehlen
>
> (possibly from the Upper Saxonian *Schmetten*; by old popular belief witches flew around in the form of butterflies to steal milk and cream.)

The article about *Schmetten* says that it’s another word for *Sahne* (cream) and comes from Czech, *smetana*.

So no, they are not related.

Comment: Are _Schmetterling_ and _Schmeißfliege_ related?

Comment: @Titus I don’t think so. How should they be related?

Comment: Irgendwie kamen mir _schmettern_ und _schmeißen_ mit einander verwandt vor. Laut [dieser Quelle](http://www.awb1.ch/dat/s/schmei_dffliege.php) stammt der Name aber aus der Jägersprache (_schmeißen_ = _scheißen_ - der Eselsbrücke zuliebe bitte ich, die profane Wortwahl zu entschuldigen).

Comment: Since the *Schmetterling* is unrelated to *schmettern* it also is unrelated *schmeißen*. Only similarity, *Schmetterlinge* were found in cream, *Schmeißfliegen* in scat.

Answer (score 4):

As idmean said *Schmette* means *Cream*.

You let the milk stay over night to let the cream settle on top of it in order to make butter out of it.
If you didn't cover your bucket properly you had *visitors* in your *Schmette*, *Schmetterlinge*. That's exact the same origin and meaning of *Butterfly*.

The witchpart is new to me.